# How to plot dataframe using XLXS writer,with multiple values in 'values' and 'categories' axis

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I need to plot a line chart of the below data frame. Columns are shown in yellow and blue need to come in the value axis(except 0.8 and 1.6) and the other three(Device_ID, Temp, and supply ) need to come in the categories axis.A sample of my data frame is given below. May I know how to approach this? Below is my code. Could you please tell me how to put more than one value in the axis.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
multi_index.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.add_series({
     'values':  '=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$'+rows,
    'categories':'=Sheet1$A$2:$A$'+rows, 
   
})
worksheet.insert_chart('F2', chart)
writer.save(
```

[image]

I run the below code

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
multi_index.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.add_series({
      'categories': '=(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$456)',
    'values':     '=(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$456,Sheet1!$E$2:$E$456)' 
   
})
worksheet.insert_chart('H2', chart)
writer.save()
```

But in the plot, only one cure was there and the X-axis parameters are coming on top.Please see the below image
[image]

Comment: How would you do what you want to do in Excel? If you can figure that out you can transfer the ranges to XlsxWriter. For example, XlsxWriter does support non-contiguous ranges, see the end of the docs on [chart.add_series()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series).

Comment: I updated the question if you don't mind could you please check it.

Comment: From an Excel point of view (not just XlsxWriter) those ranges don't look right. The number of category points is only half the number of value points. So I'll make the same point as before: figure what you need to do in Excel and then transfer those ranges to XlsxWriter.